Why is gravitational force not calculated about center of mass?
For calculation of gravitational force among two extended objects (say two rods kept in a straight line), why do we need to integrate to get the force and not by simply using $\dfrac{GM^2}{d^2}$, with $d$ being the distance between center of mass?

Why should the calculation with d being distance between the centers of mass be valid? Each atom in the two rods exerts gravity on every other atom in the two rods (and on the rest of the universe).

Hi, welcome to Physics SE. You can do it sometimes but, if you follow the arguments therein, you'll see what's assumed that's less general than you'd hoped.

If gravity did work like that, you'd get some interesting effects. Try calculating the force between a stacked pair of steel discs 1 mm thick, with radius 80 m, using that formula.

Try calculating the force of attraction of two thin concentric spherical shells with radius $r$ and $2r$. The COMs are at the same point, so the force would be infinite with your calculation.


Why is gravitational force not calculated about center of mass?

You can calculate Newtonian gravitation acceleration that way, but only in two special cases:

An object removed from a point mass, or
An object outside of a radially symmetric mass distribution.

In both cases, the Newtonian gravitational acceleration on the object in question has magnitude $\frac{GM}{r^2}$ and is pointed toward the gravitating body. In the latter case (a radially symmetric mass distribution), that this is equivalent to point mass gravitation is a consequence of Newton's shell theorem.
In the case that gravitating body is close to but not quite radially symmetric, the Newtonian gravitational acceleration on a remote object can be approximately calculated as if the central body was a point mass. The closeness of this simplifying approximation to reality depends greatly on the proximity of the two objects and on the lumpiness (the deviation from radial symmetry) of the bodies. Note well: In the case of the Earth, which is not quite radially symmetric, the Earth's equatorial tidal bulge can result in strange and counterintuitive effects on artificial satellites orbiting the Earth.
In your case (two rods kept in a straight line), Newton's shell theorem does not apply, and unless the rods are very far apart, the approximation does not apply, either.
